# Globally define kerning of math letter

Tags: typography, kerning

Is it possible to have a kerning reconfiguration in the preamble to allow a small amount of whitespace for specific letters.

In this example, I would want right space to the right of `g` and `f` when used as an italic in an equation.

Minimal Example, compiled using xelatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Adobe Minion Pro}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\let\mathdollar\relax
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \delta n_a &= \delta \left( \frac{\epsilon \partial_a f}{ \sqrt{g^{bc} \partial_b f \partial_c f }} \right) \\
        &= -\frac{1}{2} n_\mu \delta g^{bc} g_{bc} \\
        &= \frac{1}{2} \epsilon n_a n^b n^c \delta g_{ab} \qquad \qquad \epsilon n_a n^c = g^c_a - \gamma^c_a \\
        &= \frac{1}{2} n^b \delta g_{ab} + c_b \qquad \qquad c_b = -\frac{1}{2} \gamma^c_a \delta g_{bc} n^b 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Screenshot as an example

[image]

**Edit**

Included regular text around screenshot to show kerning of body text and included code of a minimal example

Comment: Please tell which math and text fonts, which document class, and which TeX engine (pdftex, detective, luatex, or something else?) you employ. Please also show the code that gave rise to the screenshot you posted. Thanks.

Comment: To me it seems the overall kerning in this font setup is really bad. As Mico says we need more information.

Comment: @Mico Sorry for neglecting more information, I have updated the post

Comment: `mathspec` has its own method for specifying a kern in these cases with `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no automatic way, sorry. The author of `mathspec` explains why. The reason is that basically `mathspec` is a kludge.

You can use `"` in appropriate places, though. For more information look in the manual.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\let\mathdollar\relax
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\delta n_a
&= \delta \left(
     \frac{\epsilon \partial_a "f}{ \sqrt{"g^{bc} \partial_b "f \partial_c "f }}
   \right) \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} n_\mu \delta "g^{bc} g_{bc} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \epsilon n_a n^b n^c \delta g_{ab}
   && \epsilon n_a n^c = g^c_a - \gamma^c_a \\
&= \frac{1}{2} n^b \delta g_{ab} + c_b
   && c_b = -\frac{1}{2} \gamma^c_a \delta g_{bc} n^b 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for expanding on your comment. This is really helpful. 

I'm trying (and failing atm) to install MinionPro as a package, which has some kerning fixes apparently. If that doesn't work, this work around with `"` might be sufficient